# Print the contents of a .txt file onto the console in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to print out the contents of a .txt file onto the console in  MIPS Assembly. I have this code but nothing is being output.

```
.data  
FileName: .asciiz "C:\\Users\\XXXX\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FileName.txt"     # filename for input
buffer: .space 3282
.text

# Open file for reading

li   $v0, 13          # system call for open file
la   $a0, FileName     # input file name
li   $a1, 0           # flag for reading
li   $a2, 0           # mode is ignored
syscall               # open a file 
move $s0, $v0         # save the file descriptor  


# reading from file just opened

li   $v0, 14        # system call for reading from file
move $a0, $s0       # file descriptor 
la   $a1, buffer    # address of buffer from which to read
li   $a2,  3281       # hardcoded buffer length
syscall             # read from file


# Printing File Content
li  $v0, 4          # system Call for PRINT STRING
la  $a0, buffer     # buffer contains the values
syscall             # print int

li $v0, 10      # Finish the Program
syscall
```

Comment: Are you running this in MARS or SPIM, or under Linux, or what?  What do you see for syscall return values when you single-step through this with a debugger?

Comment: I am running this on MARS. Unfortunetly, since this is my first time doing any coding whatsoever, I cannot answer your second question. I'm sorry if it becomes more diffficult to explain my errors

Comment: Learning to use the debugger built-in to MARS is essential.  It lets you single-step one instruction at a time, and look at registers.  Specifically, look at `$v0` after each system call.  If it's an error code, you can look it up in the table in https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html.  One thing to double-check is whether \\ turns into one or two backslashes in memory, and that your path is correct.  Perhaps use another system call to print out `FileName` and copy/paste it to a directory listing to make sure you're using a path that can be read.

Comment: I managed to single-step the code and when i'm saving the file descriptor in ```move $s0, &v0``` it shows the value ```0xffffffff```, and it continues to show in every $s0 and $v0.

I checked another thread with almost the same problem, and the OPs solution was to use two backslashes. I changed the directory to a folder in order to check if the path can be read. Still no output

Comment: `0xffffffff` is `-1`, that means error.  So it's failing to even open your file in the first place.  Maybe try with a simpler path like `"c:\\foo.txt"`.  Files in OneDrive might be special?  IDK.  Or maybe something else has the file open, and Windows sucks and won't let other programs open it.

Comment: After some tries with the path, I managed to do it! I just created a folder named "Assembly" in Documents and the path was read. Thank you very much for the help Peter Cordes!!!